# What's that message/notification called?

Tags: android, notifications, message

It's not an AlertDialog or a notification, but that gray message at the bottom that for instance appears when an application is granted super-user permissions.

I'd like to use it, but haven't got a clue what it's called. xD

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Toast.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html